# Lost Path environment variable, how to restore?

Tags: windows-7, path

Within my 15 years of PC experience I have never seen something like this.

My Path variable within the Environment Variables is deleted for some reason. And now Windows 7 shows for Windows Explorer. Notepad, calculator and everything Windows related a "not found Icon" and it can't be started either.

I even tried to get System Restore started and it can't start saying missing parameter in Environment variables.  I obviously can't get in System variables either to reset the path myself.

Is there a way to fix this or do I have to reinstall Windows for such minor thing?

Comment: What _exactly_ happens when you run a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't lose the `%PATH%` variable; you lost the association for `.exe` files.

Go to a working Win7 computer, export `HKCR\.exe` and `HKCR\exefile`.
Then, either:

- Press Windows+R, type `command.com`, type `regedit`, then import the files

If that doesn't work,

- Go to the Windows Recovery Environment (from the installation CD) on the broken machine, run regedit, mount the key `Windows\System32\Config\Software`, and apply your exported keys to the mounted file.
  (You'll need to replace `HKCR` in the exported files with whatever path you mounted the key as; you may find it easier to recreate the keys yourself)

Comment: The problem that Kave has is possible, in fact, I destroy that variable executing a bugged powershell script. I was capable to fix the problem because i destroy the user PATH variable found in HKCU:\Environment, the system PATH was intact, so i just copy the system Path found in 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' over the user path. I lost all personalized directories that i added to that variable but my session works fine again. :D

Comment: @voodoomsr: Yes.  He actually lost the association for `.exe`s.  I've seen viruses do that.

Comment: Many Thanks for your help guys.  Yes this is the exact behavior. Most executables don't seem to run, even though I was able to run ToySync 2.0 to backup my pictures and Chrome.exe was fine too. But Everything Windows related is not executable.  Maybe as you suggested it could be a Virus. I will check this tonight and report back.

Comment: Ok I am home now and the Firewall and Microsoft Security Essentials are disabled. it must be a virus. I cant even install AVAST. I sthere any command line virus scanner I could download with my laptop and check the PC with a USB stick? Many Thanks

Comment: Does `command.com` work?

Comment: you mean CMD? yes that works.  I have succeeded to press F8 at startup and get into Safe mode. From there I was able to start explorer. Then I restored the system to an earlier start point and it was fine. There I uninstalled Microsoft Security Essential and installed latest AVAST. It works fine now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `CMD` works? That's weird.  I don't know what happened.